# What does it mean halachically to not associate with the wicked?

Tags: halacha, evil-resha

Who are considered wicked? What definition of wicked is being considered here, the one in the Gemara, which I believe means a person who is predominantly evil, or the one in Tanya, where the person has unrepentant sins?

Comment: Hi @Kenny it would be helpful if you provide the sources that you allude to?

Comment: Which halacha says not to associate with the wicked?

Comment: אַל־תְּ֭קַנֵּא בְּאַנְשֵׁ֣י רָעָ֑ה וְאַל־תִּ֝תְאָ֗ו לִֽהְי֥וֹת אִתָּֽם׃
Do not envy evil men; Do not desire to be with them; [Prov. 24:1]

Comment: My source is in Pirkei Avot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first verse in the Book of Psalms says:

> אַ֥שְֽׁרֵי הָאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֤ר ׀ לֹ֥א הָלַךְ֮ בַּעֲצַ֢ת רְשָׁ֫עִ֥ים וּבְדֶ֣רֶךְ חַ֭טָּאִים לֹ֥א עָמָ֑ד וּבְמוֹשַׁ֥ב לֵ֝צִ֗ים לֹ֣א יָשָֽׁב׃
> -- Happy is the man who has not followed the counsel of the wicked, or taken the path of sinners, or joined the company of the insolent. [Psalms 1:1]

In commenting on it, Malbim answers your question:

> There is a difference between "the wicked" and "the sinners": "the wicked" sin intentionally and rebelliously, whether in matters between man and the Omnipresent or in matters between man and his fellow. That is why the Psalmist said, "the counsel of the wicked," because they are the ones who sin with counsel and intentionally whereas in regards to the "sinners", it would not be right to say "counsel" since they do sin with counsel.

Comment: Thank you. I presume this would apply to gentiles who are warned about the severity of Noachide prohibitions.